# wine1.6 download for ubuntu

Tags: wine

I have a new 32-bit ubuntu and tried to download wine1.6. I followed the instructions on the winehq site but the response was that I had to "chose an application" to proceed. Having got no further with that I used the terminal window and with sudo apt-get install wine1.6.

That was running quite well but a window labelled "configuring ttf-mscorefonts-installer" appeared which looked like a standard terms and conditions. There was an "" in the window but it was not cursor sensitive nor did "return" have any effect.

Ideas, please!

Answer (score 0):

Have you not tried downloading it from the Ubuntu Software Centre (USC)?

Open the USC and in the query box top right type in `wine`when you will be presented with the version options.

Select the version `Wine Windows Program Loader`. If it says it's already installed, perhaps try uninstalling it first then re-install.

Worked straight out of the box on my system without error.

Alternatively, you may need to reverse what you have already done from the terminal but the USC method should work (unless someone knows differently).

Personally, with my limited experience so far with Ubuntu, I find that using the USC to download programs from scratch a much more simple affair tan by using the terminal with it's associated traps for the inexperienced and unwary...